# stage 0 vs stage 4 TC39 process javascript

Tags: javascript, stage

What is the difference between stage 0 and stage 4 phase of JS changes with respect to TC39 Process of JS implementation.

Which stage code is recommended for writing production code.

P.S: I can use babel preprocessor.

Comment: Can you clarify what is unclear after reading e.g. this document? https://tc39.github.io/process-document/

Comment: *"Which stage code is recommended for writing production code"* - It's your code. Use whichever stage you feel comfortable using.

Comment: @JoeClay I know this is my code and I can add whatever I want to add. If you see my question I have clearly mentioned which one is recommended from experts like you for writing production ready code.

Comment: Read this blog: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/tc39-and-its-contributions-to-ecmascript-c178b77f32e1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, it is really depends on yourself.

As you can see, you can only be sure that a feature will be included in the standard once its proposal has reached stage 4. Then its inclusion in the next ECMAScript release is probable, but not 100% sure, either (it may take longer).

`Object.observe` is an example of an ECMAScript proposal that had progressed until stage 2, but was ultimately withdrawn.